# Fill screen with grid of child views but child views are half expected size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing a game where counters can be dragged around the screen.  I want to use an `ImageView` child view for each counter, and set absolute positions inside a `FrameLayout` parent view.

I've read some SO posts about the advantages of various layout classes over the deprecated `AbsoluteLayout`, and I don't want to use `RelativeLayout` because the counters must be moved independently of each other.  None of these posts appears to address the particular problem I'm having, though I'd be happy if someone could point me at one that does.

Here's the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_game"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff808080">
</FrameLayout>
```

Because I don't want to make assumptions about the size of the screen, I'm setting the size of each child as a fraction of the size of the parent, inside `onMeasure()`:

```
package uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin.widget

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView

class CounterView(context: Context, private val label: String, private val offset: Int) : ImageView(context)
{
    init
    {
        // Set the background color.
        val color = if (offset > 0) Color.GREEN else Color.RED
        setBackgroundColor(color)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int)
    {
        // Set the position and size.
        val parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        val size = Math.min(parentWidth, parentHeight) / 2
        val left = offset * size
        Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Parent size ($parentWidth, $parentHeight) to $label child position ($left, 0) size $size")
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size)
        layoutParams = createLayoutParams(left, 0, size, size)
    }

    private fun createLayoutParams(left: Int, top: Int, width: Int, height: Int): ViewGroup.LayoutParams
    {
        // Create a margin params object.
        val params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
        params.leftMargin = left
        params.topMargin = top
        return params
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's where I'm adding the child views to the parent:

```
package uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin.R
import uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin.widget.CounterView

class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        // Call the superclass.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

        // Add a left and right view to the group.
        val group = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.activity_game)
        group.addView(CounterView(applicationContext, "left", 0))
        group.addView(CounterView(applicationContext, "right", 1))
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image]

I would expect the red and green child views to appear side by side and fill the screen, but together they only take up half the width.  This is confirmed by the logcat output, which shows the `MeasureSpec` decoded parent width as 1080 then 540, resulting in child width 540 then 270.  This is running on a simulated Pixel 3, which has a 1080 pixel screen width:

```
2019-05-09 22:06:33.493 15575-15575/uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1808) to left child position (0, 0) size 540
2019-05-09 22:06:33.493 15575-15575/uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1808) to right child position (540, 0) size 540
2019-05-09 22:06:33.560 15575-15575/uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin I/CounterView: Parent size (540, 540) to left child position (0, 0) size 270
2019-05-09 22:06:33.561 15575-15575/uk.co.fractalmaze.counterspin I/CounterView: Parent size (540, 540) to right child position (270, 0) size 270
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. Why the parent view is resizing itself to width 540?
2. How to make the child views fill the entire 1080 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000">
        <!--child 1-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00">
        <!--child 2-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use;android:layout_width="fill_parent" instead of android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: I don't think that will do what I need.  I gave a simplified example above, and the actual game has a grid of 4x4 counters; AIUI a `LinearLayout` forces the child views to be lined up horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Also, I need to (i) create the child views in code not XML because the board size can change, and (ii) change their absolute positions according to user actions.

Comment: I was hoping someone would be able to tell me why the parent view is resized to 540x540 when the child views should take up 1080x540.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried setting `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on the parent view XML, but it made no difference.  I also tried using a `LinearLayout`, and while it did allow child views to be placed at different positions, it still resized the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but I'm not sure why it works.  I changed `CounterView.onMeasure()` so it creates the layout parameters with the desired size of the *parent* view:

```
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int)
    {
        // Set the position and size.
        val parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        val parentSize = Math.min(parentWidth, parentHeight)
        val size = parentSize / 2
        val left = offset * size
        Log.i(javaClass.simpleName, "Parent size ($parentWidth, $parentHeight) to $label child position ($left, 0)")
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size)
        layoutParams = createLayoutParams(left, 0, parentSize, parentSize)
    }
```

This was the result:

[image: Android Simulator]

Note that the logcat output shows the parent view size *not* being halved:

```
2019-05-10 17:51:16.335 18623-18623/? I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1808) to left child position (0, 0)
2019-05-10 17:51:16.336 18623-18623/? I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1808) to right child position (540, 0)
2019-05-10 17:51:16.386 18623-18623/? I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1080) to left child position (0, 0)
2019-05-10 17:51:16.389 18623-18623/? I/CounterView: Parent size (1080, 1080) to right child position (540, 0)
```

This is enough to let me continue writing the application, but can anyone explain what's going on here please?